# joblib - the parallel code takes more time than the non-parallel code

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I am first time using joblib. I am using jupyter notebook on windows. it is 16 core machine. It seems that my code runs much slower when using joblib parallel processing compared with single process. I can see that joblib created processes to the do the job. But all of them used less than 2% CPU except one using 6% CPU. So in total, it only used up to 11% CPU. I am not sure what I have done wrong. Below is my codes

prepare_function.py

```
def intersect_fire(index, grid_cell, index2, fire): 
    if grid_cell['geometry'].intersects(fire['geometry']): 
        grid_index=index
        UUID=fire.UUID
        data = {'GridIndex':grid_index,'geometry':grid_cell['geometry'].intersection(fire['geometry']),'UUID':UUID}
    return data
```

Parallel processing code

```
%%time
from prepare_function import intersect_fire
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(intersect_fire)(index, grid_cell, index2, fire) for index, grid_cell in poly1.iterrows() for index2, fire in poly2.iterrows())
    data =[x for x in data if x is not None]
```

I also tested using some example codes from online and it is the same only using 7% CPU in total.

test_function.py

```
def multiple(a, b):
   return a*b
```

joblib parallel processing code

```
%%time
from test_function import multiple
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(multiple)(a=i, b=j) for i in range(1, 6000) for j in range(11, 1600))
```

Comment: ON LINUX : `import os ; os.system("taskset -p 0xFFFFFFFF %d" % os.getpid())`

Comment: Unfortunately I used Windows. And that's could be the reason why I have this issue. Do you know how to fix this for Windows.